# Why do I get a “Hive support is required to CREATE Hive TABLE (AS SELECT)” error when creating a table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I'm running into an issue when trying to create a table.

Here is the code to create the table, where the exception is occurring:

```
sparkSession.sql(s"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydatabase.students(" +
s"name string," + s"age int)")
```

Here is the spark session configuration:

```
lazy val sparkSession = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("student_mapping")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate()
```

And this is the exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Hive support is required to 
CREATE Hive TABLE (AS SELECT);;'CreateTable `mydatabase`.`students`,
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, Ignore
```

My question is: Why is this exception occurring? I have several other spark programs running with the same session configurations, running flawlessly. I'm using Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.3.

Comment: can you make sure that database exists ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for checking. I do have a line to create the database right before creating the table: `spark.sql(s"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydatabase")`

Answer (score 9):

> SparkSession is the entry point to Spark SQL. It is one of the very
>   first objects you create while developing a Spark SQL application.
>
> SessionState is the state separation layer between Spark SQL sessions,
>   including SQL configuration, tables, functions, UDFs, SQL parser, and
>   everything else that depends on a SQLConf.
>
> SessionState is available as the sessionState property of a
>   SparkSession
>
> Internally, sessionState clones the optional parent SessionState (if
>   given when creating the SparkSession) or creates a new SessionState
>   using BaseSessionStateBuilder as defined by
>   spark.sql.catalogImplementation configuration property:
>
> in-memory (default) for
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionStateBuilder
>
> hive for org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder

For using hive you should use the class `org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder` and according to the document this can be done by setting the property `spark.sql.catalogImplementation` to `hive` when creating SparkSession object:

```
val conf = new SparkConf
      .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://namenode/sql/metadata/hive")
      .set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","hive")
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .setAppName("Hive Example")

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config(conf)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
```

or you can pass the property `--conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive` when you submit your job to the cluster.

Comment: I'm getting the error even after setting catalogImplementation to hive. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

It worked by passing --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive to spark-submit.
This was not needed in spark 1.6 but it seems needed since spark 2.0

Answer (score 1):

[Citing](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-hive-metastore.html):

> By default, Spark SQL uses the embedded deployment mode of a Hive metastore with a Apache Derby database.

In other words, by default Spark's sql context doesn't know about any tables managed by Hive on your cluster.

You need to use Hive's metastore (storage knowing of databases and tables in Hive) in Spark to be able to manipulate them from Spark application.

To do so you need either set `spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` if you are using embdedded metastore, or `hive.metastore.uris` for accessing metastore via Thrift protocol in case of metastore in remote db.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like your answer was on the right path. I tried setting my hive.metastore.uris, which did not work, but I eventually found the solution to my problem by setting the catalogImplementation to hive in my spark submit. ``--conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive``

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and where should I add --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive setting. I am getting the exact same error.